# Defining Safe zone

Tags: android

I am developing an application which will send a alert message when that particular person goes out of the safe zone. I am using GPS to track the location information. Can anyone suggest me some ideas on how to set the safe zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Best way to do that; Calculating position and proximity on Mobile phone with Built in Proximity Alerts**

You should create basic server application to keep all safe zones in your database. That server application also should generate some definition file (xml or json) to transfer all safe points to Android application. 
Then your application can download that safe points from your server.

*Example area definition json file;*

```
{"areas": [
{"area-name": "Dangerous areas in NY",
 "danger-score": 5,
 "coordinates": [
    {"lat": "00.00000","lon": "00.00000", "radius": 2},
    {"lat": "00.00000","lon": "00.00000", "radius": 5},
    {"lat": "00.00000","lon": "00.00000", "radius": 10},
    {"lat": "00.00000","lon": "00.00000", "radius": 25}
]},
{"area-name": "Less Dangerous areas in NY",
"danger-score": 2,
 "coordinates": [
    {"lat": "00.00000","lon": "00.00000", "radius": 25},
    {"lat": "00.00000","lon": "00.00000", "radius": 50},
    {"lat": "00.00000","lon": "00.00000", "radius": 12},
    {"lat": "00.00000","lon": "00.00000", "radius": 45}
]}
```

]}

Your application can poll users current location in every X minute. (Just think about the battery life!) For calculating distance to safe points you can user Android built in function "Proximity Alerts".

[Android Proximity Alert Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

[Example project which is pretty close to your case.](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/07/part-1-developing-proximity-alerts-for-mobile-applications-using-the-android-platform/)

Happy coding...